# MySQL insert query error

Tags: mysql, database, insert

Whats wrong with this query. I'm getting an error saying

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Item 1') where ItemName like 'Item 1' at line 1

My query is

```
insert into newitem (QuantityAvailable) values 
(Select count(*) from  addtoinventory where ItemName like 'Item 1') 
where ItemName like 'Item 1'
```

Comment: Why do you repeat your `WHERE` clause?

Comment: How logical is that an insert statement has a WHERE clause?

Comment: the first where clause is for the nested query. I'm counting all those rows with item name like "Item 1" and the second where clause is for the insert where I'm inserting into those rows (the output of nested query) where Item name like "Item 1"

Comment: What should be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take out the word *values* from your query.

Also, I don't see what you expect the where clause to do in the outer query. If you haven't inserted a value yet, how can you compare it to anything? If you have, then the inner where clause takes care of that.

Comment: I'm so sorry for asking this stupid question. I am still in a party mood.. I should use update newitem rather than insert into .. !!

Answer (score 0):

insert into newitem (QuantityAvailable) Select count(*) from  addtoinventory where ItemName like '%Item 1%'